# Align multiple equation (vertically and horizontally) + vertically dotted line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, pdftex, vertical-alignment

I have read posts describing how to align equations vertically and horizontally. Unfortunately it does not work. Does anyone know how to fix the following code?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  w_1 &= u_1,
&
 v1 = w1 / \left\lVert w_1\right\rVert
\\
  w_2 &= u_2 - \langle u_2, v_1\rangle v_1, 
&
  v_2 = w2 / \left\lVert w_2\right\rVert
\\\\
  w_p = u_p - \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \langle u_p, v_i\rangle v_i, 
&
  v_p &= w_p / \left\lVert w_p\right\rVert
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Additionally, I would like to add a vertically dotted line between the equations:

w2 = u2 - ... and wp = up - ...

and

v2 = w2/... and vp = wp/...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply forgot that two alignment points per line require `3 &`.
Here is a solution using the `\vdotswithin` command, from `mathtools`, to align the vertical dots with the = signs, and some vertical adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm} \lVert \rVert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\innerp} \langle \rangle

    \begin{document}

   \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  w_1 &= u_1,
&
 v_1 & = w1 / \norm*{w_1}
\\
  w_2 &= u_2 - \innerp{u_2, v_1} v_1,
&
  v_2 & = w_2 / \norm{w_2}
\\[-0.5ex]
 & \vdotswithin{=} & & \vdotswithin{=} \\
  w_p & = u_p - \smash[t]{\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}}\innerp*{u_p, v_i}v_i
& v_p &= w_p / \norm{w_p}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  w_1 & = u_1,
&
 v_1 & = w_1 / \lVert w_1 \rVert
\\
  w_2 & = u_2 - \langle u_2, v_1\rangle v_1, 
&
  v_2 & = w_2 / \lVert w_2 \rVert
\\ & \vdots && \vdots \\
  w_p & = u_p - \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \langle u_p, v_i\rangle v_i, 
&
  v_p & = w_p / \lVert w_p \rVert
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Also, it's not related with your specific question, but the `\left` and `\right` commands used here are useless, since the vertical bars from `\lVert` and `\rVert` do not have to get any bigger to fit their content.